# Vector Tracing a Line Around Non-Square Sprites in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, vector-graphics

I'm building a game in HTML5. I have hundreds of images that look similar to this:

[image]

And at certain points in the game I want to draw an outline around them. Like this:

[image]

I want to do different tracing colors at different times and don't want to end up with [number of sprites] * [number of colors] of additional images for memory and bandwidth reasons so I'm looking at vector drawings.

What I need to come to a solution on are really two separate things:

1. Calculate a vector path for each frame in a spritesheet. This can be either dynamically or ahead of time and stored.
2. Draw the vector path

The engine I'm using for the game is ImpactJS. It doesn't have any support for vector operations. The author of the game engine I'm using did his own vector drawing manually by exporting the vectors from Illustrator for a particular image, then using an online converter tool to change them to HTML5 syntax. This isn't the best method for hundreds of images so I thought I'd see what information others of you have.

I would like to still draw the images using ImpactJS since this game is already pretty far along, and just do a second-pass drawing of the outline of the image when necessary.

Thank you for any help!